# how to solve undefined method `model_name' for 1:Fixnum error ( ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

on click on submit it should go to update_settings method of dashboard_controller. on click i gets this error.How to solve this

Any help is appreciatable

`undefined method`model_name' for 1:Fixnum`

`[image]

i have my routes like this

`namespace :generic_users do
    root to: 'dashboard#show'
    get 'settings', to: 'dashboard#settings'
    patch "settings" => "dashboard#update_settings", :as => "update_settings"
  end`

my dashboardcontroller is like this

`class GenericUsers::DashboardController<ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def settings
    @title='Generic Users Profile Management Page'
    @generic_user = current_user.specific.id
  end
  def update_settings
     @generic_user = GenericUsers.find(current_user.specific.id)
    if @generic_user.update_attributes(sign_up_params)
      redirect_to generic_users_root_path, flash: {notice: "Your details have been updated"}
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
  private
    def sign_up_
  end
  private
    def sign_up_params
    params.require(:generic_user).permit(:username,:mobile,:firstname,:lastname, :email,:image,:referred_by,:address)
    end
end`

in views/dashboard folder, view file called,
 settings.html.erb

```html
  <%= simple_form_for(@generic_user, :url => generic_users_update_settings_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :username, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :firstname, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :lastname, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :mobile, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :image, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :referred_by, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.label :address, "Address" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :address, required: true, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

also have a model generic_user.rb
Please give me a solution to this error.
i have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `model_name' for 1:Fixnum

You need to change the `@generic_user` in `settings` method as below

```
def settings
  @title='Generic Users Profile Management Page'
  @generic_user = GenericUsers.find(current_user.specific.id)
end
```

The first argument in the `simple_form_for` should be a ***record***.